# SQL CASE in TRIGGER

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers, case

I have 2 databases in SQL Server 2012
I am trying to create a trigger to update a table from one database to a table in the second database that will contain a history of tasks
I am "trying" to use a CASE expression in the update statement but I keep getting an incorrect syntax error: Incorrect syntax near '='
This is the trigger:

```
USE [Employees]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trigger_task_list]
ON [dbo].[Employee_Timesheets]
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET EMPID = CASE WHEN EMPID = 2  THEN 'Carol'     
             WHEN EMPID = 3  THEN 'Joan'          
             WHEN EMPID = 4  THEN 'Jess'         
             WHEN EMPID = 5  THEN 'Linda'        
             WHEN EMPID = 6  THEN 'Tanya'     
             WHEN EMPID = 7  THEN 'Sarah'        ELSE EMPID END

SET TaskNo = CASE WHEN TaskNo = 10 THEN 'Prepare Invoices' 
              WHEN TaskNo = 20 THEN 'Log Invoices'             
              WHEN TaskNo = 30 THEN 'Print Invoices'       
              WHEN TaskNo = 40 THEN 'Run Reports' ELSE TaskNo END

SET NOCOUNT ON

INSERT INTO employeedashboard.dbo.task_list_history (emp_id,dep_id,task_id,date_time)

SELECT EMPID AS emp_id, department as dep_id, (SELECT TaskNo FROM Employee_Timesheets WHERE TaskNo = 20) AS task_id, GETDATE() AS date_time

FROM inserted 

END
```

Any advice suggestions to resolve this / optimize the query I'd really appreciate it

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your code doesn't make much sense.  Why are names embedded in a trigger and not a reference table?  Why are you mixing types in a `case` expression?

Comment: Where's the `END` for the `CASE`? Also, you cannot do what you are trying. You should either use variables, or integrate the `CASE` statement into the `SELECT` part of the query.

Comment: I updated the question with the END for CASE - when I added that I still get the initial Error and Incorrect Syntax near 'SET'. Expecting CONVERSATION

Comment: No @AaronBertrand I looked at the documentation on the Microsoft website - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO employeedashboard.dbo.task_list_history (emp_id,dep_id,task_id,date_time)

SELECT 
    CASE WHEN EMPID = 2  THEN 'Carol'     
       WHEN EMPID = 3  THEN 'Joan'          
       WHEN EMPID = 4  THEN 'Jess'         
       WHEN EMPID = 5  THEN 'Linda'        
       WHEN EMPID = 6  THEN 'Tanya'     
       WHEN EMPID = 7  THEN 'Sarah'        
       ELSE EMPID 
    END AS emp_id
    , department as dep_id
    , TaskNo = 
       CASE WHEN TaskNo = 10 THEN 'Prepare Invoices' 
          WHEN TaskNo = 20 THEN 'Log Invoices'             
          WHEN TaskNo = 30 THEN 'Print Invoices'       
          WHEN TaskNo = 40 THEN 'Run Reports' 
          ELSE TaskNo 
    END AS task_id
    , GETDATE() AS date_time
FROM inserted
```

Note, this is untested, and purely based on my interpretation of what I *think* you're trying to do...

I agree with Gordon, though. Rather than coding the case statement here, store those value in a lookup table you then join to. This will ensure you can easily add or remove values in the future, without requiring a code change.

Comment: Cheers for the suggestions - the values are already stored in a separate table - unfortunately the database is a rat's nest and I don't have permissions to alter certain tables - The table I am inserting to also retrieves values from other sources - the values need to be presented in "plain English"  as there is a dashboard connected to the database using php - I don't have permission to alter that select statement either :)

Comment: @EdwardDoyle - Sounds like quite the hoops they are having you jump through.

Comment: it is - square pegs in round holes :(

Comment: @EdwardDoyle Either slap someone and then run, or just run ;)